# mysql search to get some number of result and count of all match in one query

Tags: mysql

i have a large query to show my table data in some pages 
and each page have 50 record

my query is like this :

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) icount,GROUP_CONCAT(page_num) pages FROM files 
                                    left join user_files on files.id = user_files.file_id 
                                    left join file_contents on files.id = file_contents.file_id 
                                        WHERE (files.status='C' or files.status='L') and user_files.vc_status='active' and
                                            (
                                            (user_files.perm='ALL') or 
                                            (user_files.perm='MIN' and user_files.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]' ) or
                                            (user_files.perm='CUS' and ufid in (select doc_id from file_permissions where file_permissions.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) or
                                            (user_files.perm='GRP' and ( (select group_id from group_files where file_id=user_files.ufid) 
                                                            IN (select group_id from group_users where user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) )
                                            )
                                            AND
                                            (user_files.description LIKE '%$newSearch%')
                                            OR
                                            (user_files.title LIKE '%$newSearch%')
                                            OR
                                            MATCH (file_contents.body) AGAINST ('$newSearch') OR MATCH (file_contents.body) AGAINST ('$newSearchRev')
                                            GROUP by files.id ORDER BY files.id DESC limit 50;
```

> **query explain**:*the table `files` save file data the `user_files` save users data whom uploaded the file and `file_contents` is saving
>   files content data*

this query return 50 record to show in my result first page but also i need all match row count to make a pagination...

the simple way is run query twice and just remove `limit 50` from the end.

but there isn't any way to avoid two query time ?

Comment: When you do count query it does not take time. Or does it?

Comment: now after above query i run it without limit and get all match row count.the first query take about 8 second to run and count query need about 50% of first query time!!

Comment: But that's a one time query.

Comment: i dont understand.you mean when i run query two time, one that showing above and one without `limit 50` in php and this take one time?

Comment: I mean avoiding two queries doesn't seem like a big improvement here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of rows of a `LEFT JOIN .. GROUP BY` query, the query can be simplified. You can remove any part of the query, which doesn't change the number of rows. Consider the following example:

```
select a.id, count(c.id) as cnt
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.a_id = a.id
left join table_c c on c.b_id = b.id
where a.x like '%search%'
   or b.y like '%search%'
group by a.id
```

In this case `table_c` is irrelevant for the row count, because it is left joined and there is no condition using data from that table. It is only relevant for the value of `count(c.id) as cnt`, which you don't need in your second query. So all you need here is `table_a`, `table_b` and the same WHERE clause. You also don't need a GROUP BY clause - You just count the number of distinct values of columns from the original GROUP BY clause. So the final COUNT query would be:

```
select count(distinct a.id) as num_rows
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.a_id = a.id
where a.x like '%search%'
   or b.y like '%search%'
```

In your case it would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT files.id) as num_rows
FROM files 
    left join user_files on files.id = user_files.file_id 
        WHERE (files.status='C' or files.status='L') and user_files.vc_status='active' and
            (
            (user_files.perm='ALL') or 
            (user_files.perm='MIN' and user_files.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]' ) or
            (user_files.perm='CUS' and ufid in (select doc_id from file_permissions where file_permissions.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) or
            (user_files.perm='GRP' and ( (select group_id from group_files where file_id=user_files.ufid) 
                            IN (select group_id from group_users where user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) )
            )
            AND
            (user_files.description LIKE '%$newSearch%')
            OR
            (user_files.title LIKE '%$newSearch%')
            OR
            MATCH (body) AGAINST ('$newSearch') OR MATCH (body) AGAINST ('$newSearchRev')
```

Note: I didn't check if your original query is correct or makes sense.

#### Update

One possible way to improve the performance is to use a *UNION optimization*. Since there must exist a fulltext index on `file_contents.body`, the following query should be quite fast:

```
SELECT fc.file_id
FROM file_contents fc
WHERE MATCH (fc.body) AGAINST ('$newSearch $newSearchRev')
```

I'm assuming, that

```
MATCH (fc.body) AGAINST ('$newSearch $newSearchRev')
```

is equivalent to

```
MATCH (file_contents.body) AGAINST ('$newSearch') OR
MATCH (file_contents.body) AGAINST ('$newSearchRev')
```

but can actually use the index.

Now you can split the base query into two parts. One part without joining the `file_contents` table and the other only with that table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as row_count
FROM (
    SELECT files.id
    FROM files 
        left join user_files on files.id = user_files.file_id 
            WHERE (files.status='C' or files.status='L') and user_files.vc_status='active' and
                (
                (user_files.perm='ALL') or 
                (user_files.perm='MIN' and user_files.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]' ) or
                (user_files.perm='CUS' and ufid in (select doc_id from file_permissions where file_permissions.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) or
                (user_files.perm='GRP' and ( (select group_id from group_files where file_id=user_files.ufid) 
                                IN (select group_id from group_users where user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) )
                )
                AND
                (user_files.description LIKE '%$newSearch%')
                OR
                (user_files.title LIKE '%$newSearch%')

    UNION DISTINCT

    SELECT fc.file_id
    FROM file_contents fc
    WHERE MATCH (fc.body) AGAINST ('$newSearch $newSearchRev')
) u
```

Note that all you need, is to count distinct file IDs. I'm also assuming that any `file_id` in the `file_contents` table also exists in the `files` table.

This technique can possibly be applied to other OR conditions. But for that, one needs to understand them.

#### Update 2

Though the question was only about the count query - But if the performance improvement of the UNION query is high, you should consider to use it for your base query too. What you need to do is to apply the LIMIT and OFFSET in the UNION subquery and then join it with the base query. For the first page (`OFFSET 0`) the query would be:

```
SELECT files.*,COUNT(*) icount,GROUP_CONCAT(page_num) pages
FROM (
    SELECT files.id
    FROM files 
        left join user_files on files.id = user_files.file_id 
            WHERE (files.status='C' or files.status='L') and user_files.vc_status='active' and
                (
                (user_files.perm='ALL') or 
                (user_files.perm='MIN' and user_files.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]' ) or
                (user_files.perm='CUS' and ufid in (select doc_id from file_permissions where file_permissions.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) or
                (user_files.perm='GRP' and ( (select group_id from group_files where file_id=user_files.ufid) 
                                IN (select group_id from group_users where user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) )
                )
                AND
                (user_files.description LIKE '%$newSearch%')
                OR
                (user_files.title LIKE '%$newSearch%')

    UNION DISTINCT

    SELECT fc.file_id
    FROM file_contents fc
    WHERE MATCH (fc.body) AGAINST ('$newSearch $newSearchRev')

    ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
) u
inner join files on files.id = u.id
left join user_files on files.id = user_files.file_id 
left join file_contents on files.id = file_contents.file_id 

WHERE (files.status='C' or files.status='L') and user_files.vc_status='active' and
    (
    (user_files.perm='ALL') or 
    (user_files.perm='MIN' and user_files.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]' ) or
    (user_files.perm='CUS' and ufid in (select doc_id from file_permissions where file_permissions.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) or
    (user_files.perm='GRP' and ( (select group_id from group_files where file_id=user_files.ufid) 
                    IN (select group_id from group_users where user_id='$_SESSION[uid]') ) )
    )
    AND
    (user_files.description LIKE '%$newSearch%')
    OR
    (user_files.title LIKE '%$newSearch%')
    OR
    MATCH (file_contents.body) AGAINST ('$newSearch $newSearchRev')
    GROUP by files.id ORDER BY files.id DESC
```

Yes, it's huge now, because all conditions are repeated. But note that the outer WHERE clause is only applied on the filtered 50 file ids.

Comment: my original query is correct and have result but my question is to get a better time!! and i cant remove `file_contents`table  because the `body` is in that table.i updated my query.

Comment: @peimanF. I couldn't know that. That's why you should always use table prefixes for all columns. So well.. then you can't remove `file_contents`. All I can think of, to improve the performance even more, is to use a UNION optimization for your OR conditions. But that also applies to your original query, and would be a different question.

Comment: Thank you you mean , at all there is no a standard command to get all match count and some of the output results?

Comment: There is a **deprecated** feature [FOUND_ROWS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows), which I have never used in real code, since I (usually) can optimize my LIMIT queries. Usually there are good reasons, why something is deprecated.

Comment: BTW: Did you test my suggested query after including back the file_contents table? How does it perform compared to the original LIMIT query?

Comment: good,your update return the row count very faster the original query.so i can use this to get row count for paging! but because of use `union` i cant get other fields to grab file list and etc...

Answer (score 0):

Get all records save them in the collection (depends what backend language you use) and then you can fetch 50 first entries, so you are avoiding double SQL query.

Comment: this is really hard if we have a large number of match rows... running query twice is better solution then your solution...

Comment: That's true we need to keep in mind memory limits. Depends of expected record size.